# Debug в CodeBlocks

Tags: отладка, codeblocks

Чтобы запустить программу(дебажить) от курсора нужно нажать F4, я нажимаю появляется консоль ввода, но когда я ввожу в консоль, то выдается ответ и она закрывается, то есть отладка прекращается(. На shift + F7 все работает, но очень долго проходить все до курсора. Помогите пожалуйста!
P.S. названия и путь правильные

Comment: 1. Он не доходит до этого места кода по каким то причинам, программа завершается раньше. 2. Проверьте что __c::b__ находиться в дебаг версии сборки для цели. 3. Проверьте наличие в опциях ключей сборки для дебаг цели ключа `-g`. 4. Выполнить до места - удобнее вызывать из контекстного меню мыши, первая строчка. 5. Для профилактики, в меню отладка, удалите все точки останова для проекта, иногда с ними глючит, если их много.

Comment: А как 2 пункт сделать, что-то я не совсем понял.

Comment: хмм.. в тоолбаре выпадающий список с целью сборки, обычно по умолчанию там 2 цели: `Debug` и `Release` - если вы ничего не переименовали в опциях проекта.

Comment: Ну да, там debug, но все равно не помогает, хотя все так как вы сказали ранее.

Comment: Пункт 1, или интересующий вас код находится в другом потоке, как предположение. Попробуйте до него дойти в ручном режиме, туда вообще попасть можно? Или поставьте точку останова и проверьте.

Comment: Да все возможно, я же писал, что на shift+F7 все работает отлично, но долго все проходить до нужного места, а run to cursor не работает. Тут проблема в codeblocks, а не в коде, так как run to cursor не работает вообще ни с каким проектом.

Comment: Это странно, приведите панель настройки дебагера (скриншот) и номер версии __c::b__. И вы используете gdb?

Comment: Номер версии 17.12, использую gdb.

Answer (score 0):

У вас стоит `system("pause")` или `getch()` в конце программы?
Дебагер не задерживает программу в конце.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Много пробовал. Помогло только то, что на пути к дебагеру и к самому проекту не должно быть русских символов вообще. Удачи с решением проблемы.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).